# GDB Stack Trace incomplete info

Tags: gdb

I am debugging using gdb a C application which uses an installed library(wrote in C).
The library is running as daemon process and accepts requests from application and process it.
To debug the library daemon I have attached it in gdb and have loaded the libraries symbol file at proper address using commands "info sharedlibrary" and "add-symbol-file".

I have set the source code path using the dir command.

But still the **stack trace does not show the file name and line numbers**.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf76b2377 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xf616196d in MySemaphoreWait () from /opt/demo/lib/libdemo.so.0
#3  0xf6130fe5 in ReadFile () from /opt/demo/lib/libdemo.so.0
#4  0xf77870df in ?? () from /opt/demo/lib/libtest.so.0
#5  0xf778016e in ?? () from /opt/demo/lib/libtest.so.0
#6  0xf77584b9 in ServiceRequest () from /opt/novell/lib/libtest.so.0
#7 0xf7744c8a in Demo_Main () from /opt/novell/lib/libtest.so.0
```

What might be the reason the same and how get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have attached it in gdb and have loaded the libraries symbol file at proper address using commands "info sharedlibrary" and "add-symbol-file".

On Linux, attaching the process should be sufficient for GDB to load symbols from all shared libraries, and `add-symbol-file` should not be required.

As a guess, you did something like this:

```
make install COPT=-O2  # build/install optimized version of libtest.so.0
# start daemon using it
make COPT=-g  # build debug version of libtest.so.0
gdb -p <daemon-pid>
(gdb) info shared
(gdb) add-symbol-file /path/to/dbg-version/libtest.so.0 <address>
```

That doesn't work, because optimized and debug builds produce totally different binaries with totally different symbol values.

What you want to do is *install* debug version, restart daemon, and debug that (you wouldn't need `add-symbol-file` in that case).

Alternatively, you may want to do this:

```
make COPT='-g -O2'
```

That builds a matching *optimized* version, but with debug info. You can then use `add-symbol-file` to point GDB to the optimized version with debug info.

Beware: debugging optimized code is (relatively) hard. Don't expect `next` command to take you to the next line, don't expect to be able to examine all the variables, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I removed the optimization using -o0.